# Returning a Stream object and ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, exception, stream

In C# code, I observed the `ObjectDisposedException`'s occurrence in an ASP.NET application and its generic error handler in a middleware, but because of missing details in the message I was not able to catch the closed file mentioned. The message looks always the same: "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.".

BTW, without details about the source of error, this technique (of handling error in a common pipe) seems to be a little... frustrating, at least. Anyway:

I guessed the file operation causing the exception was related to my changes. (Shame.) Fortunately, it was not so much volume of changes. My candidate was a Stream object returned from inside of `using` statement.

```cs
public Stream GetStream(string path)
{
    using (var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        return fileStream;
    }
}
```

Why this exception was raised?

Comment: You return the stream to use it somewhere but you disposed it before usage here. Find a different/better spot to dispose the filestream. Just not disposing isn't really a solution.

Comment: If you are returning the stream then obvioulsy you wouldn't want to dispose it now. Where is it being used, you should dispose it there

Comment: You are right, thank you - I will update my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code from the question is not correct - if I return the stream, the outer code should be responsible for disposing it. The correct version should look like this:

```cs
public Stream GetStream(string path)
{
    return File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
}
```

Thanks to the commenters.

Comment: The code is correct, why you say it's not?!? It compiles and returns the Stream object, exactly as method name says, so it's correct. Maybe logic behind is wrong?
Well, if this is the case, maybe you could return the content of the file instead of the stream?
Or, you could store the stream object in a privare variable inside the class and make the class disposable, so when it's disposed you can close the stream...

Comment: @Marco it's because the returned steam is disposed when it's returned in the original designed. It's because of how "using" works.

Comment: Thank you, folks, for your comments. Now this should be better.